# Combine KML overlays to find overlapping shapes and export to flat file

Tags: kml, export, overlapping-features

I have two KML files with many polygons each.

One has larger area polygons while the other has smaller areas. They overlap with each other and I would like to know which areas overlap with each other and export this data to CSV or a similar flat file.

Eg If KMLOne has a large polygon and KMLTwo has 5 polygons that overlap it then I would like to see which polygons overlap. Also if any polygons overlap but are not 100% overlapping with KMLOne then that should be marked as overlapping as well.

An example of how I would like this displayed is below where KMLOne has polygon with name 1 and KMLTwo has several polygons that overlap it.

```
+--------+--------+
| KMLOne | KMLTwo |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      1 |      4 |
|      1 |      5 |
+--------+--------+
```

Is there a program that can perform this functionality?

Please let me know if you require any clarification.